# If a vector $v_1$ from some subspace $V$ is added to another vector $v_2$ and the result is in $V$, does that imply that $v_2$ is in $V$?

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-writing

I am working through a problem in Sheldon Axler's linear algebra book with subspaces. In one of my proofs I use this argument:

Given $v \in V$ and $u$ may or may not be in $V$: $$\text{if}\ v+u \in V\ \text{then}\ u\in V$$
The argument came from the idea of closure under addition of a subspace and that if some addition is closed in the subspace then both elements are already in the subspace. However closure under addition does not state anything with addition outside of the subspace.

This argument made sense to me at first, but now I am having my doubts but cannot think of a counterexample to disprove this. Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Vector subspaces are closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  Hence $(v+u)-v\in V$.

Comment: If $w=u+v$, then $u=w-v$, which is an element of $V$, since both $w$ and $v$ are elements of $V$.

Comment: Closure under addition alone is not enough. For example, consider $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Then $2 + -1 \in \mathbb{N}$, but $-1 \notin \mathbb{N}$. The fact that $\mathbb{N}$ contains $0$ and is closed under $+$ is not sufficient.

Comment: But $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be applied here because $\mathbb{N}$ does not have the fundamental properties of a vector space right? Namely that of a 0 vector as well as an additive inverse on the set.

Answer (score 0):

Note $u = (u+v)-v$ is in $V$, being a linear combination of the elements $u+v$ and $v$ of $V$.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot and makes a great deal of sense. I did not think about having the additive inverse of $v$.